# Buffering calendar

Tags: bug

My calendar, as depicted here, endlessly buffers:

[image]

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I checked it just now and I am also facing the problem.

Comment: This happens on all sites, not only on Math SE. It has already been reported on the Main Meta: [Visited Calendar pop out on user activity pages missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392624/196432) .

Comment: @Martin: Whether or not it's the same bug, I couldn't say. But the calendar bit was definitely working for me this autumn. (It doesn't now.)

Comment: I believe the problem is resolved.  I check every day, and this morning the calendar pop-out appears correctly on the dozen or so sites I check.

Comment: @hardmath I just checked and yes, it is working for me now as well.